# how do i add my certificate to cordova when building an app?

Tags: cordova

How do I compile my apps with my developer certificate keys when using cordova from the command line?

By default it uses a debug certificate key, how do I use the one that I use when i'm  building using the online phonegap build tool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Remove the console plugin:

   ```
   D:\projects\Phonegap\Example> cordova plugin rm org.apache.cordova.console
   ```
2. To generate a release build for Android, we first need to make a small change to the AndroidManifest.xml file found in platforms/android.

   Edit the file and change "android:debuggable" to "false".
3. Now we can tell Cordova to generate our release build:

   ```
   D:\projects\Phonegap\Example> cordova build --release android
   ```

   Then, we can find our unsigned APK file in platforms/android/ant-build. In our example, the file was `platforms/android/ant-build/Example-release-unsigned.apk`.
4. Note: you want to create key, please proceed with the following steps.

   Key Generation Syntax:

   ```
   keytool -genkey -v -keystore .keystore -alias -keyalg -keysize -validity
   ```

   Examples:

   ```
   keytool -genkey -v -keystore NAME-mobileapps.keystore -alias NAMEmobileapps -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
   ```

   ```
   keystore password? : xxxxxxx
   What is your first and last name? : xxxxxx
   What is the name of your organizational unit? : xxxxxxxx
   What is the name of your organization? : xxxxxxxxx
   What is the name of your City or Locality? : xxxxxxx
   What is the name of your State or Province? : xxxxx
   What is the two-letter country code for this unit? : xx
   ```

   Then the Key store has been generated with name as NAME-mobileapps.keystore
5. Place the generated keystore in `D:\projects\Phonegap\Example\platforms\android\ant-build`

   To sign the unsigned APK, run the jarsigner tool which is also included in the JDK:

   ```
   jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore
   ```

   Example:

   ```
   D:\projects\Phonegap\Example\platforms\android\ant-build> jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore NAME-mobileapps.keystore Example-release-unsigned.apk xxxxxmobileapps
   Enter KeyPhrase as 'xxxxxxxx'
   ```

   This signs the apk in place.
6. Finally, we need to run the zip align tool to optimize the APK. Run either of the following:

   ```
   D:\projects\Phonegap\Example\platforms\android\ant-build> zipalign -v 4 Example-release-unsigned.apk Example.apk
   ```

   ```
   D:\projects\Phonegap\Example\platforms\android\ant-build> C:\Phonegap\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140624\sdk\build-tools\android-4.4W\zipalign -v 4 Example-release-unsigned.apk Example.apk
   ```

   Now we have our final release binary called example.apk and we can release this on the Google Play Store.

Comment: Not sure why this questions was down voted to -3, this information is just as relevant in 2019 as it was in 2014.